# X-Y Co-Ordinates input on slow fling are more but less on fast fling

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I m working on a android app, which takes X-Y co-ordinates as input using openGL. The Problem is when we draw slow (fling slow) the input co-ordinate points are more and input co-ordinate points are less on fast fling.

I would like to know to the reason why it happens, So as to optimize and have same number of co-ordinates on touch with any speed/motion.

Since stackoverflow requires 10 reputation i could not upload images.. pls see the links below for images

fast moment : https://www.dropbox.com/s/rvdlz79mr2iowtx/fast_moment.png?dl=0
slow moment : https://www.dropbox.com/s/n2px7wcjw62wfi8/slow_moment.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is how touch events are working. Your touch screen may report new touch coordinates but your system needs to collect those data which generally happens every X milliseconds. This results in getting N points per second rather then N points per distance made.

If you wish to have a relatively same amount of points per distance you should do a bit of an extra processing on the points you get. To begin with when the press is dragged you should always remember the last point received and when a new one comes you should compute the distance from the last one and if the distance is not long enough simply discard the point.

Note that this is only a first step but some more might need to be introduced so I suggest you create some class that will handle this for you and report to your target system.

So the first issue with this system you will most likely introduce is you will lose the last point sometimes because it might be too close to the one before it, so you need to handle the last point specifically.

Then if the drag was too fast you might find yourself having too little points in which case you should use some interpolation. It might be enough to simply interpolate lineally (an average of two points) but generally you would want to create a nice curve interpolated between at least 3 points to get a nice curve.

So what I suggest in general is to create a trace class that will hold all the points you receive from touch events (until the finger is lifted). Then on every point received you should analytically generate the new array of points from the ones gotten by the events and report them to the target system.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I will try applying some algorithm to generate new array based on last point touched and new point with relative to distance